# Can I send media segments to the Google Cast media source?

Tags: google-cast, media-source

I assume Google Cast uses the Media Source API. Is there any way to send media segments to the device? I have a video stream that needs to be preprocessed.

Comment: It depends. Much of the MediaSource API is supported.  TS segments aren't yet.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Yes, I want to play an encrypted video file with some non-standard encryption. I want to have the device play the decrypted segments. Is there an example of using the MediaSource API with the Cast? Is the API supported on the device or the client?

Comment: No source code as of yet.  The API is on the device. (and in current Chrome)